How do I establish an open connection to an open web browser in C#?
How do I establish an open connection to an open web browser in C#?
In a Microsoft C# program using a Visual Studio Code I am using the following namespaces:
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
After I get a string variable, "url", assigned with a URL of a website page, I use the following commands which successfully opens a browser window and loads the web site:
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
But this opens a chrome browser which is denoted somewhere as being a "test" session.  It somehow knows it was launched from a program.  And, since I am using this program to automate some interactions with linkedin, this information is passed along to linkedin which prompts me that it requires I login.  This creates a cascading seriies of events that are difficult to automate including using my cell as a means of verification.
So, instead of taking this route, how do I establish an open connection to an open web browser in C#?  I figure, if I instead connect to a web browser that is already open and already has its veriication steps done with linkedin, then I won't be prompted to log in and do any user verification.
On a personal note, if this is intentional security measures to prevent people from abusing a system, then this is a sad thing.
On a broader view, will all this mean I will have to make a web browser from scratch?

Please format the code in your question. (While for newcomers I'd be happy to do it for them as an example, as you've posted over 300 questions I think it's reasonable to expect you to do it yourself at this point...)

This question is similar to: Use Selenium to attach to a manually opened Browser. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
